# Read-string doesn't output complete string clojure

Tags: string, clojure, lisp

I am fairly new to functional programming. I am learning clojure. I was trying out a few commands. Some of them work fine.  I got this weird one below:

```
(read-string "1 2 3")
;;this ouputs
1
```

---

```
(read-string "[1 2 3]")
;;this ouputs
[1 2 3]
```

I am wondering why in the first one it doesn't output the complete string.
but does output it in the second one.
     1 2 3

Any reason for this?

---

In case you are wondering, i was doing this on command line. It shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your examples output a string.

As the docstring says: "Reads one object from the string s."

In the first case the object is `1`, in the second case the object is `[1 2 3]`.

To output a string the object needs to be a string, e. g. `(read-string "\"1 2 3\"")`

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of "string" in the name `read-string` is meant to indicate that its argument is a string, not its return value. The point of it is to parse a single piece of clojure syntax from the given string, which it is doing in both of your examples. The string `"1 2 3"` contains *three* forms instead of just one. `read-string` always parses and returns a single form, so returning `1` is the expected behavior here.